# Generating time-series data with known statistics

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, simulation

When I try to implement a parameter estimation method for the first time, such as Maximum Likelihood estimation, I first sample data from a probability distribution, such as a Gaussian distribution, with known parameters, such as mean and variance, and then try to estimate this mean and variance given only the data. I find this helpful because it gives me an idea of how accurate my estimates are.

I am now trying to do the same thing with a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) using audio data. Each audio signal is 3,000 samples long, and my objective is to reconstruct this audio signal. However, I am having trouble getting it to work, as my VAE just reconstructs the mean of the audio signal (straight line). I think this has to do with my architecture.

To try and solve this problem, I am thinking of instead sampling audio data of the same length (3,000 samples) from a joint Gaussian distribution with a known mean vector and covariance matrix, training the VAE, and checking if I can correctly estimate the mean vector and covariance matrix. This should at least help me check if my VAE architecture is correct.

I think one problem with this approach is that my audio signals are clearly non-stationary, meaning their mean and covariance are time-dependent. This means that my stationary sampled audio data will not closely replicate the real audio data.

I have two questions:

1. Is this the right approach to fixing my VAE problem?
2. How can I correctly sample audio data from a known probability distribution such that it closely mimics the real audio data? I am aware that this is not an easy task, but I just want to know what the best way is to do this.
3. Is it still worth the effort to train my VAE using stationary Gaussian data even if my real data is non-stationary?